# aws routing issue with site to site vpn

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, routing

I will appreciate your help with this one.

I have the following:

1. One VPC
2. One virtual private gateway
3. Two customer gateways (site to site vpn).

I have one production site, and one DRP site. The DRP site is a full replica of the production site Including the internal address (both have the same local address).
I have one CGW connected to my production and the routing tab is setup to the local subnet address in my Lan. it works with no issues.
I have also created a second CGW to the DRP site and entered at the routing tab the same settings as in production .
This causes a problem, once the DRP site is up, I lose connection to the production site.
I know it's because of the routing settings. In other installaiton with regular routers i would setup different "cost" and
"priority" so the traffic will go only to the production path, and only if the line will go down It will flow to the DRP path. The thing is i don’t know how to make that settings in AWS routing .

Or maybe the VPGW is setup to do it automatically?(i didnt test it by disconnecting production site to aws)
Is there a way to setup routing priorities in the VPGW ? 
my goal ,as you understand , is to have the VPC connected to both sites, but have communication flow only to the Production site ,and only in case of line failure to switch to the DRP site.
Thanks